# Enumeration Swift 4 - Qual a sua utilidade e como ele funciona para o desenvolvimento IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Bom galera, estou estudando muito para começar desenvolver um aplicativo em **Swift 4** para uma entrevista de emprego, porém o Type Enum me deixou um pouco, quase nada, porém, ainda sim, confuso.

Eu queria saber um pouco mais sobre esse elemento da linguagem **Swift 4**, como ele funciona, alguns exemplos de aplicações do **Type Enum**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Enum é a maneira de delimitar determinado aspecto do seu código, você pode usar ele para especificar um numero finito de possibilidade que podem ocorrer no seu código, exemplo:

uma simples calculadora, voce pode por exemplo fazer uma função passando os dois valores e a operação:

```
func calculate(lhs: Double, rhs: Double, operation: String) -> Double {
    switch operation {
    case "+":
        return lhs + rhs
    default:
        return lhs - rhs
    }
}
```

porém dessa maneira se você esta dando a possibilidade de passar qualquer coisa e nunca saberá ao certo se o que está chegando é sempre uma operação e sempre que não for cairá em subtração, com um enum você saberá sempre o que vai receber pois será do tipo enum, sendo assim não precisa necessariamente de um default, já que você tem controle de todas possibilidades como no exemplo:

```
enum MathOperator {

    case sum
    case subtraction
    case multiplication
    case division

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    func calculate(lhs: Double, rhs: Double, operation: MathOperator) -> Double{
    switch operation {

    case .sum:
        return lhs + rhs
    case .subtraction:
        return lhs - rhs
    case .multiplication:
        return lhs * rhs
    case .division:
        return lhs / rhs
    }
}
```

você pode usar enum pra definir variáveis estáticas globais, ou seja que você vai usar em mais de uma classe como por exemplo valores:

```
enum StaticValues: Double {
    case pi = 3.1415926
    case inch = 2.54 // cm
    case mile = 1.609344 // metter
}
```

e usando o seu valor "cru":

```
print("20 polegadas é igual a: ", StaticValues.inch * 20, "mm")
```

a diferença entre usar este enum e uma classe comum com valores guardados em constantes estáticas como:

```
class StaticValues {
    static let pi = 3.1415926
    static let inch = 2.54 // cm
    static let mile = 1.609344 // metter
}
```

é que um enum você não pode instanciar e a classe MathOperator alguém poderia, sendo assim o enum é mais seguro.